# Packaging Apache configuration files with WAR

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, apache

I have built a Spring 3 MVC driven RESTful web service app. I use Maven 2 to manage the application lifecycle including packaging up the WAR for distribution. As part of the end solution, I filter application requests through Apache to handle some of the GET requests for static content. This of course requires that I have several custom configurations in Apache configuration files.

My question is this, I would like to package and version these Apache configurations with ( not inside) the WAR, is there a clean way to do this? (using maven?)

Currently, the configuration changes are just included as installation instructions.

Comment: One solution I played around with was a .patch file for configuration changes and the maven assembly plugin to make the file available at build. I was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is this, I would like to package and version these Apache configurations with (not inside) the WAR, is there a clean way to do this? (using maven?)

I'd put such files in a dedicated module (with a `pom` packaging) and use the Maven Assembly Plugin to create a `.zip` archive to be unzipped on the target machine(s) and that would be part of the delivery.

Worked pretty well in the past.